# mongoose query: find an object by id in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

How could I find an image by id in this Schema. I have the id of the User and the id of the image I am looking for. What would be the best way to do this and do all images in this case have different ids or could they have the same id because they don't belong to the same User?

My Schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    email: String,
    password: String
  },
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
  },
  name: String,
  about: String,
  images: [{
    id: Schema.ObjectId,
    link: String,
    main: Boolean
  }]
});
```

Comment: Are you interested in the full object or just the image with the specified id?

Comment: I would prefere a full object with just one image that has the passed id.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are interested in the full object it is a simple `find`:

```
.find({"facebook.id":"<id>", "images.id":<image-id>})
```

I don't think that there is a way to reduce the image array in the result.

To update a single element in the image array you can use this:

```
.update({"facebook.id":"<id>", "images.id":<image-id>}, {$set : {"images.$.main" :false} } );
```

Comment: well that is my problem exactly. I need to update one field in just that one image and dont know how to get to that image. Any other toughts? And i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
userSchema .find({facebook.id: "some ID",{ "images.id": { $in: [ id1, id2, ...idn] }}
```

since images are inside the document you can have same ID's however every time you query you should keep in mind that you send some other parameters such as facebook.id or facebook.email along with image id's to retrieve them. Otherwise you end up getting all that might be irrelevant only because you decide to keep same ID's for images.

Answer (score 0):

##### tl;dr

I struggled with this and came up with a solution.  Like you, I was trying to query for a deeply nested object by the `_id`, but I kept coming up empty with the results.  It wasn't until I did some type checking that I realized the `id` value I was getting from my frontend, while directly supplied by mongoose, was in fact a `String` and not an `Object`.

I realize this question was already partially answered before, but that person's solution didn't work for me, and the comment on the answer tells me you wanted to update the specific image you queried for, which is exactly what I was trying to do.

#### The solution

In order to select an object from the nested array by the `_id` value, first you'll have to install the npm package `bson-objectid` and use the provided method to convert your string into an `objectId` in your query.

**In your terminal:**

```
npm i bson-objectid
```

**In your code:**

```
const ObjectId = require('bson-objectid')

userSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "facebook.id": <user-id>, "images._id": ObjectId(<image-id>) },
    { "$set": { "images.$.main": false } }, 
    { new: true }, // an extra options parameter that returns the mutated document
    (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            handleErr(err)
        } else {
            console.log(user)
            // do something with new user info
        }
)
```