# mongoose find collection by _id in a list of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here's my Schema

```
var PositiveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    name: String,
    restrictAwardTo: Object
})
```

Now `restrictAwardTo` saves the data in this format

```
"restrictAwardTo" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5c31907d908eb8404657cbf0",
            "firstName" : "Admin 2a"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5c1a7677c98da061141475a8",
            "firstName" : "Justice"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5c1a7677c98da061141475a9",
            "firstName" : "Itik"
        }
    ],
```

How can I search inside my document using one of the `_id` listed under `restrictAwardTo`? I tried the solutions given below

- [mongooseJS find docs with IDs in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499024/mongoosejs-find-docs-with-ids-in-an-array/48509187#48509187)
- [mongoose query: find an object by id in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596865/mongoose-query-find-an-object-by-id-in-an-array) but it returns empty.
- in Robo3t `db.getCollection('positives').find({ 'restrictAwardTo._id' : ObjectId('5c31907d908eb8404657cbf0') })`

Update: In Robo3t, this query `db.getCollection('positives').find({ 'restrictAwardTo._id' : {$in: ['5c1a7677c98da061141475a7']} })` works. Now I'm making it work for mongoose too.

Comment: Can you add a full sample input document and expected output in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mongoose that works for me:

```
Positive.find({ schoolID:  mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(schoolID), "restrictAwardTo._id": { $in: [userID]} })
```

But I'm not entirely sure of the performance for large records.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through this way.

```
Positive.findOne({'restrictAwardTo': {$elemMatch: {_id: userID}}}, 
        (err,schoolInfo) => { });
```